# asp.net mvc 4 httppostedfilebase not passing to controller when using ajax modal popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview, httppostedfilebase

There are some similar topics in forums, but there isn't any good answer. First question is that is it possible to pass httppostedfilebase to controller, when using modal popup?
When I am using regular model and view, then everything is working well, but as soon I make this view as partialview, then everything except file is passing to controller. File is getting null value.

### List View where modalpopup is excecuting:

```
<button style="cursor:pointer" type="submit" class="fluent-big-button" onclick="ShowModal('@Url.Action("Create", "Device")')" >
```

### Modal Popup View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Device", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-horizontal">           
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Resources.Insert_New_Device</legend>   
        <div class="grid" style="margin: 0px auto">
            <div class="row" style="margin: 0px auto">
                <div class="span10">
                    <div class="row" style="margin: 0px auto"> 
                        <div style="white-space:nowrap" class="span2 readable-text"><label>@Resources.Device_No:</label> </div>
                        <div class="span3">               
                            <div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.No, new { required = "required", autofocus = "autofocus", @tabindex="1"})
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.No)
                                <button tabindex="-1" class="btn-clear" type="button"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="white-space:nowrap" class="span2 readable-text"><label>Tootja:</label> </div>
                        <div class="span3">               
                            <div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Manufacturer_Name, new { autofocus = "autofocus", @tabindex="2"})
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Manufacturer_Name)
                                <button tabindex="-1" class="btn-clear" type="button"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>       

                    <div class="row" style="margin: 0px auto">

                        <div style="white-space:nowrap" class="span2 readable-text"><label>Pilt:</label> </div>
                        <div class="span3">                
                                <div class="fallback">
                                    <input type="file" name="DeviceImage" id="DeviceImage" />
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin: 0px auto">
                    <div class="span10">@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </fieldset>        
</div>       
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="grid" style="margin: 0px auto">
            <div class="row" style="margin: 0px auto">
                <div class="span4"></div>
                <div class="span3"> 
                    <button class="button large span3" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <input class="large span3 success" type="submit" value="Ok" />
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
}
```

### Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.exsistingDevices = GetExsistingDevices();
        return PartialView("_Create");
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Device device, HttpPostedFileBase DeviceImage)

    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                SPDBContext db = new SPDBContext();
                device.Last_Action_Date = DateTime.Now;


                // Insert image

                if (DeviceImage != null)
                {
                    if (DeviceImage.ContentLength > (2 * 1024 * 1024) && DeviceImage.ContentLength < 1)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "File size must be less than 2 MB");                          
                    }
                    var contentType = DeviceImage.ContentType;
                    device.Image = new byte[DeviceImage.ContentLength];
                    DeviceImage.InputStream.Read(device.Image, 0, DeviceImage.ContentLength);
                }
                db.Devices.Add(device);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", String.Format("{0}: {1}",Resources.Resources.Insert_Failed, e.Message));
        }
        return PartialView("_Create", device);
    }
```

### Model:

```
[NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase DeviceImage { get; set; }

public byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and remove all the code that's not relevant to this problem? Cheers.

Comment: Please construct a MWE. I have a feeling what *might* be the problem, however, if that feeling is correct, then the real problem is not displayed here. Just edit the question as suggested before.

Comment: Thank You very much the probleem was with modal popup and serialize. Here is some more information and correct answer to that problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563289/file-upload-in-mvc-when-used-in-bootstrap-modal-returns-null